# Using updateWhere inside a map / forM

Tags: haskell, yesod, persistent

Each element in a list will trigger some DB updates but I keep getting stuck with the return type. Could you please let me know what's the correct way to do this?

```
for ::  [a] -> (a -> b) -> [b]
for xs f = map f xs

-- Summary: Loop over the elements of xs and update the table for each element
-- get an ID from the element
-- get the record corresponding to that ID
-- extract more values
-- update table (below is just a dummy updateWhere 
-- but the above values will be used in the update eventually )
forM_ xs $ \(Entity xid val) -> do
            let qid = tableField val 
            y <- runDB $ get404 qid
            let z = table2Field y
            return $ updateWhere [PersonName ==. "Test"] [PersonAge *=. 1]
```

I get the following error:

```
Couldn't match type `PersistMonadBackend m0'
               with `persistent-1.2.1:Database.Persist.Sql.Types.SqlBackend'
Expected type: PersistMonadBackend m0
  Actual type: PersistEntityBackend Person
In the second argument of `($)', namely
  `updateWhere [PersonName ==. name] [PersonAge *=. 1]'
```

I tried using  `for` instead of  `forM or forM_` and it does not fix anything. At this point, I am just trying a whole bunch of combinations without really understanding how to fix this error. Appreciate your help!

**Update:**

Here is the actual code that I am working with. When I get rid of most of the let statements and just run updateWhere with a trivial update it still gives me the same error.

```
getCalculateDeltaR :: personId -> Handler Html
getCalculateDeltaR personId = do

    goods <- runDB $ selectList [GoodPerson ==. personId] [] 

    forM goods $ \(Entity gid good) -> do
                let aid = goodAsset good  
                asset <- runDB $ get404 aid
                let mktValue = assetMktValue asset
                return $ updateWhere [GoodPerson ==. personId, GoodAsset = aid] [GoodDelta =. (mktValue - GoodOrigValue)]  

    defaultLayout $ do
        $(widgetFile "calculateDelta")
```

If I change the forM above to:

```
    forM goods $ \(Entity gid good) -> do
                return $ updateWhere [GoodPerson ==. personId] [GoodDelta =. 1]
```

I still get the same error about mismatched types.

Comment: Does it work when you remove the return in the last line of the lambda?

Comment: @bennofs I am new to Haskell so I cannot say if it 'works' but without the return it tells me: "The last statement in a 'do' block must be an expression".  I don't know if that means as long as I can return a proper expression back things will work. When I use updateWhere outside of forM it works fine. My guess is something to do with the 'do' but I could be way off here.

Comment: Can you show a bit more code, maybe the function where you use the block of code you posted, including it's type signature?

Comment: @bennofs Thanks for your help. I have updated my post now. The code runs inside a Handler

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not very familar with yesod, but I think the following code should work:

```
forM_ xs $ \(Entity xid val) -> do
        let qid = tableField val 
        y <- runDB $ get404 qid
        let z = table2Field y
        runDB $ updateWhere [PersonName ==. "Test"] [PersonAge *=. 1]
```

You don't want to return DB Actions and then throw them away (forM_ throws the individual return values away), because that would just result in no action. You have to run them.

Comment: Thanks @bennofs. I feel stupid -- was staring at the code for a while but did not realize I never ran the action. Thank you very much for the help.